# Turning Javascript into a widget

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a tool take people can use and its made in Javascript.
They generate the code and then paste it into their webpage code.

I am just wondering how would I go about making it work in forum posts, or other site posts or do the websites normally block this sort of thing?

Would it be possible to convert it for social media sites also? Like have it so the users can interact with it inside posts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first a warning: **DO NOT DO THIS THE WAY THAT YOU HAVE IT RIGHT NOW**

You are forcing people to inject a script directly into their website directly from your servers. This script sets and users global variables and can break other things. I would be very *very* angry if someone added something like this to a site I ran. For example your script creates a function called `clicked()` in the global scope. What if the site already had a function named that on it? Then all of a sudden that site breaks. It is possible to do this without these issues ([see how twitter buttons work for example](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#hashtag)) but it still has limitations.

Doing this in the way you have it set up looks to another site exactly like an XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attack so no, you cannot do this in forums/etc - they specifically disallow it.

Occasionally a forum might allow iframes (they have much better security for the including site). In your case using iframes would actually be a much cleaner solution. Simply have them include an iframe that points to your site. Your site then (using php, .Net, node, perl, whatever server scripting language you want) would reply with the markup that you want. You can pass the parameters you want as parameters in your url.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it this way